# How to make the first alphabet of the word capital?

Tags: python, string

This is my code:

```
for names in whats_app_marketing['City']:
    city_names=names.title()
    whats_app_marketing['City']=city_names
```

However, this code is not working fine. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your example and include code to set those variables such that we can run it and reproduce your result.  It seems that your problem is not how to capitalise words,( you have found `.title()`) but how to `append` items to a list.

Comment: Whats the contents of `whats_app_marketing['City']` given your code i assume its a list of some iterable, but you then replace that with a single value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your city data is a list of cities. You could just use a list comprehension to rebuild the list with upercase letters.

```py
whats_app_marketing = {}
whats_app_marketing['City'] = ['glasgow', 'edinburgh', 'london']

print(whats_app_marketing['City'])
whats_app_marketing['City'] = [city.title() for city in whats_app_marketing['City']]
print(whats_app_marketing['City'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['glasgow', 'edinburgh', 'london']
['Glasgow', 'Edinburgh', 'London']
```

if the value of your city key is not a list or standard iterable then you would need to provide its data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using capitalize():

```
for names in whats_app_marketing['City']:
    city_names=names.capitalize()
    whats_app_marketing['City']=city_names
```

Comment: this will have the same issue as the OPs code, yhou are taking an iterable and replacing it with a single string value so will lose your list/tuple/iterable data

Comment: `'new york'.capitalize()` is `'New york'` - not sure if this is intended

Answer (score 0):

```
    cities=[]
for names in whats_app_marketing['City']:
    city_names=names.title()
    cities.append(city_names)
whats_app_marketing['City']=cities
```

This also worked, I just had to make another list. Chris Doyle said it right where he told about the replacing single value string. Thanks anyway !